# Social login error during Gmail verification

Tags: django, django-allauth

**settings.py**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
'google': {
    'SCOPE': ['profile', 'email'],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'},
},
'facebook': {
   'METHOD': 'oauth2',
   'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
    'FIELDS': [
        'id',
        'email',
        'name',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'timezone',
        'gender',
        'updated_time'],
    'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
    'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'kr_KR',
    'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    'VERSION': 'v2.4'
},
```

}

I'm redirected to choose an account option using allauth. But after i choose an account I get redirected to a page "social network login failure".

- Authorized JavaScript origins: http://localhost:8000
- Authorized redirect URIs: http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of to remove allauth, as it is already tagged. Also made your English a bit clearer and removed use of **bold** where it is not needed. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, your particular error with the information you are given is difficult to find out but you can get extra information following the advice given in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728887/debugging-django-allauth-social-network-login-failure#36728888