# Code: unknown, Error: Invalid response while obtaining request token from "api.twitter.com" - how to obtain and print Twitter error message

Tags: django, twitter, django-allauth

I am using [Django Allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) with Django 2.0.8 and 3.5

I have followed the instructions for using Twitter to login to a site. However, when I attempt to login to my website, I am getting the following message:

> Social Network Login Failure
>
> An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account.

There is no log output containing more information - which makes debugging this unnecessarily difficult. Based onan answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728887/debugging-django-allauth-social-network-login-failure), I have added information to my tempate which sheds some more light:

> Code: {{ auth_error.code }}, Error: {{ auth_error.exception }}

However, the error message is:

> Code: unknown, Error: Invalid response while obtaining request token from "api.twitter.com"

Which doesn't help very much. I want to see the actual response returned by the twitter.api, so I can get to the bottom of the problem - however, it is not obvious to me how to output or log the **ACTUAL** response obtained from the twitter API.

How do I see/capture the Twitter API response when I attempt to login using django-allauth?

Comment: Did my solution help you resolve the problem?

Comment: @argo, thanks I just saw this message notification. I'll check this evening when I get home and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the django-allauth code I could find the logic which is giving you the following error. [Error Code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth/client.py#L78)

```
        if response.status_code not in [200, 201]:
            raise OAuthError(
                _('Invalid response while obtaining request token'
                  ' from "%s".') % get_token_prefix(
                      self.request_token_url))
```

This shows that if the response code is not successful i.e. 200 or 201 then it would raise this exception. So you can see that it is raising an error without doing much of logging the response.

There might be other ways to log response, but that would need some help from the maintainer of the library or someone who has explored the whole library.

Now coming to your question, how can you log this response. The simplest way that I see is to edit the local file `socialaccount/providers/oauth/client.py` in your server and place a logger. The new file `socialaccount/providers/oauth/client.py` would look something like this:

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = "django_allauth_response.log"
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=20000000, backupCount=2)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
......... 
.........
same code as in allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth/client.py
.........

logger.info("Response of authentication:" + str(response)) #add this line
if response.status_code not in [200, 201]:
    raise OAuthError(
        _('Invalid response while obtaining request token'
          ' from "%s".') % get_token_prefix(
              self.request_token_url))
```

After this once you run it in your server then you can open the `django_allauth_response.log` file and check the response.

**P.S.** There might be few minor tweaks needed for setting up the logger and also mostly you have to work little more on the string conversion of the response.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this problem twice with Twitter, and both times the issue was the callback URL. One time I didn't put the trailing / on the end. The next time, I was using a callback URL that used www. at the beginning, but was accessing the site from a different subdomain.

Also, I did as previous poster suggested and modified the file client.py within AllAuth, but I found I could just output the errors to the web by

```
            raise OAuthError(
                _('Invalid response while obtaining request token'
                  ' from "%s". (' + str(response.status_code) + ') and (' + str(response.text) + ')') 
                    % get_token_prefix(
                      self.request_token_url))
```

Comment: Hi Johnny! remember me?