# Trouble getting Salesforce login working with dj-rest-auth + django-allauth

Tags: django, salesforce, django-allauth, django-rest-auth, jsforce

My app has a Django 3.1 backend with [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) and [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth) (actively supported fork of [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth)).

My mobile and web frontends can already sign in using Facebook and Google via REST. I'm now trying to add Salesforce as a 3rd REST social login method, but am running into issues.

I've followed the [django-allauth instructions for Salesforce](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#salesforce):

- Created a Salesforce Connected App with id and openid scopes (along with some others), and set the callback URL to `https://www.mywebdomain.com/accounts/salesforce/login/callback/`
- Created a SocialApplication in Django with client ID, secret, and login URL in the "Key" field (https://login.salesforce.com/)
- Included allauth.socialaccount.providers.salesforce in INSTALLED_APPS

I've been using client-side [JSforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) to kick off the Salesforce auth request in the frontend, but I'm open to other methods if they are simpler/better/etc.

Running `jsforce.browser.login()` in my clients' JS code opens a Salesforce login popup. After entering Salesforce login credentials, the Salesforce system redirected to my defined  callback URL, resulting in a page that shows the following text:

> Social Network Login Failure
> An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account.

The URL in the address bar on that page looks something like this:

```
https://www.mywebdomain.com/accounts/salesforce/login/callback/#access_token=00D3t000004QWRm%21ARwAQPfHWiM6jdB43dlyW6qjEw._34mjzGi_Jv6YCXp0QssT.9F9lCge5_YaH8gqTy3Od6SywCs8X9zOGv145SyviBVeGdn0&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fna123.salesforce.com&id=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00D3t000004QWRmEAO%2F0053t000008QBetAAG&issued_at=1606802917608&signature=KvxAX0WBCFQYY%2BO25id9%2FXxpbh2q2d2vWdQ%2FFV5FCBw%3D&state=jsforce0.popup.c0ockgct29g&scope=id+api+web+refresh_token+openid&token_type=Bearer
```

I tried to debug and print the error in my backend, but both `auth_error.code` and `auth_error.exception` were blank/empty.

I also tried sending the `access_token` from that URL's hash to my Salesforce API endpoint (see below), but that resulted in a 400 error ("Incorrect value").

Here is how I've defined my `SocialLoginView`s in my views.py, based on [dj-rest-auth's social auth documentation](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#social-authentication-optional):

```py
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.salesforce.views import SalesforceOAuth2Adapter


class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter


class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter


class SalesforceLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = SalesforceOAuth2Adapter
```

My urls.py:

```py
from .views import FacebookLogin, GoogleLogin, SalesforceLogin

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    # Sending access_token to the Facebook and Google REST endpoints works,
    # but doing the same for the Salesforce REST endpoint does not (400 error: "Incorrect value")
    url(r'^api/rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
    url(r'^api/rest-auth/google/$', GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google_login'),
    url(r'^api/rest-auth/salesforce/$', SalesforceLogin.as_view(), name='salesforce_login'),
    ...
]
```

How can Salesforce social auth be made to work in this app?

Comment: The error message you provided is incomplete.  Can you subclass the default template to include the full message?  Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36728888/10746224) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: @ElrondSupportsMonica auth_error.code is `unknown`, auth_error.exception is `None`, and auth_error.extra is an empty dict.

Comment: What (if anything) do you see in Salesforce setup -> this user -> scroll all the way down to login history. Looks like you received access token (session id) OK? urldecode it, it must have sf org id (see SF setup-> company information) followed by "!" in it, not "%21". And send a GET request to what you got as the "id" url (`https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D3t000004QWRmEAO/0053t000008QBetAAG`) with `Authorization: Bearer access_token_goes_here`, see if it returns anything sensible. You can use Postman, curl or whatever http client you want).

Comment: Also - play with https://openidconnect.herokuapp.com/ ? It'll be all manual OAuth2 "dance" but should help you figure out how to configure django. And it'd be server-side thing (user still safely directed to sf login page but no JavaScript, no reading stuff from "#fragment" in the url). SF has lots of OAuth2 options, maybe there's better one for you? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5

Comment: Are you sure this can be done like that? I've only seen SSO enabled Salesforce (Community User) logins for 3rd-party apps (but that does not say much).

Comment: I believe JSForce's authentication from the browser is meant to handle the OAuth directly, not through an underlying framework. I expect you need to remove JSForce from the project entirely and leverage something like django-salesforce. Otherwise you'd have to hand JSForce the secrets -- which means the browser has them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and got it working: when posting to my dj-rest-auth Salesforce API endpoint, I was only including `access_token` in my POST body. I actually need both `access_token` and `key`, where `key` is the Salesforce login URL (`"https://login.salesforce.com"`).

It was indeed in the [django-allauth instructions for Salesforce](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#salesforce), but I misinterpreted the wording. I now know that it says to require both `access_token` and `key` in the POST body.